# Implement STACK class using linked structure

Tags: visual-c++

I want to Implement a STACK class using linked structure to store the following information about students:
i. Registration number of the student
ii. Name of the student

I want to write client code, such that based on the registration number of students,
Then I want to retain only the record of the students enrolled in the fall semester and pop out all the student
records enrolled in the spring semester.
Students enrolled in spring semester have their registration number start from f like f010123 and students enrolled in spring have their registration number start from s.
I know to implement stack using array but not using linked list.I want to know which type of data members will be in stack class and what will be the parameters in push and pop function.I did not know that how both name and registration no. will be implemented together in a linked list.  I just need help to understand its basic idea. Then I will myself proceed this code. Can anybody help me to solve this problem??
Thanks in Advance